# How can I apply product range filters using MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, filter, where-clause, between

I'm struggling to solve this problem for one of my project. I'm using codeigniter 3 and MySQL 8. So please help me experts. Here is the description.

I'm having 2 tables as follow:

Product:

```
| id | name      |
| -- | --------- |
| 1  | Product 1 |
| 2  | Product 2 |
| 3  | Product 3 |
| 4  | Product 4 |
```

Product Filters:

```
| product_id | filter_id | value  |
| ---------- | --------- | ------ |
| 1          | 1         | 60     |
| 1          | 2         | 40     |
| 2          | 1         | 400    |
| 2          | 2         | 30     |
| 3          | 1         | 80     |
| 3          | 2         | 20     |
| 4          | 1         | 50     |
| 4          | 2         | 100    |
```

SQL for your easy reference:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Product 1'),
  ('2', 'Product 2'),
  ('3', 'Product 3'),
  ('4', 'Product 4');
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_filter` (
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `filter_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `product_filter` (`product_id`, `filter_id`, `value`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '60'),
  ('1', '2', '40'),
  ('2', '1', '400'),
  ('2', '2', '30'),
  ('3', '1', '80'),
  ('3', '2', '20'),
  ('4', '1', '50'),
  ('4', '2', '100');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c071f

For a one product there can be multiple filters as above. But cannot have same filter twice. For each product, each filters can have a value.

I want to have the following scenario:

- filter 1 and value between 0 to 200 **and**
- filter 2 and values between 0 to 50.

For instance, I'm having 10 power adaptors. I want to filter it out using voltage and watts. So, filter 1 will be voltage and 2 will be watts. Now I sending range values to filter the specific product by consumption of 0 - 200 volts and 0 - 50 watts. I mean these both condition should be apply.

Resuts should be the list of products:

```
| id | name      |
| -- | --------- |
| 1  | Product 1 |
| 3  | Product 3 |
```

I tried the following sql using multiple **AND**s, its return an empty result. this is a sample query I used.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
JOIN product_filter fp ON fp.product_id = p.id
WHERE
(
   fp.filter_id = 1 AND fp.value >= 0 AND fp.value <= 200
) AND 
(
   fp.filter_id = 2 AND fp.value >= 0 AND fp.value <= 50
)
```

How can I achive the above answer? Please help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a number that is simultaneously less than 0 and greater than 100?

Comment: Yes, I update the question.

Comment: I didn't get what you said?

Comment: btw, a product cannot have same filter id twice. So, for a specific filter it gets a value only onece.

Comment: So a value for `value` where  `value <= 0 AND value => 200` is ...? And a value for `filter_id` where `(filter_id = 1 AND ...) AND (filter_id = 2 AND ...)` is ...? PS [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: I just got it. It was my mistake while I'm typing the sample code. That's not the real problem here. Please give me a solution if you guys can.

Comment: Thanks for your help on MCRE. Hope the question is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT product_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN filter_id = 1 THEN value END) v
     , MAX(CASE WHEN filter_id = 2 THEN value END) w
  FROM product_filter
 GROUP
    BY product_id;

+------------+------+------+
| product_id | v    | w    |
+------------+------+------+
|          1 |   60 |   40 |
|          2 |  400 |   30 |
|          3 |   80 |   20 |
|          4 |   50 |  100 |
+------------+------+------+
```

So, for our purposes, this can be rearranged as...

```
SELECT product_id
  FROM product_filter
 GROUP
    BY product_id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN filter_id = 1 THEN value END) BETWEEN 0 AND 200
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN filter_id = 2 THEN value END) BETWEEN 0 AND 50
   ;

+------------+
| product_id |
+------------+
|          1 |
|          3 |
+------------+
```

Note that this is unlikely to be more efficient than your idea of (LEFT) joining the table lots and lots of times, but it can be easier to read.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer. Working perfectly.